# How do I append list outputs from Python requests into a single list without duplicates

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python requests to get data back from an API.
Here is the code, please ignore all the parsing in the middle, it is just the suggested way of getting the required resources.

```
class_url = f"https://species-ws.nbnatlas.org/species/{taxon_id}"
        class_response = requests.get(class_url)
        class_json = class_response.json()

        jsonpath_exprr = parse('$..classification')
        class_resources = [ match.value for match in jsonpath_exprr.find(class_json) ]

        r = re.compile("(?!.*id)")
        taxon_level_names = list(filter(r.match, list(class_resources[0].keys())))

        jsonpath_exprr = parse(f'$..classification.{taxon_level_names}')
        class_resources = [ match.value for match in jsonpath_exprr.find(class_json) ]
        

        print(class_resources)
```

The above code is nested within a for loop and hence returns multiple lists as a response.
The response to this looks something like this:

```
['Tetrapoda', 'Animalia', 'Columbiformes', 'Aves', 'Columba', 'Chordata', 'Columbidae', 'Columba palumbus', 'Columba palumbus']
['Tetrapoda', 'Animalia', 'Passeriformes', 'Aves', 'Turdus', 'Chordata', 'Turdidae', 'Turdus merula', 'Turdus merula']
['Tetrapoda', 'Animalia', 'Passeriformes', 'Aves', 'Erithacus', 'Chordata', 'Muscicapidae', 'Erithacus rubecula', 'Erithacus rubecula']
['Tetrapoda', 'Animalia', 'Passeriformes', 'Aves', 'Cyanistes', 'Chordata', 'Paridae', 'Cyanistes caeruleus', 'Cyanistes caeruleus']
['Tetrapoda', 'Animalia', 'Passeriformes', 'Aves', 'Corvus', 'Chordata', 'Corvidae', 'Corvus corone', 'Corvus corone']
['Tetrapoda', 'Animalia', 'Passeriformes', 'Aves', 'Parus', 'Chordata', 'Paridae', 'Parus major', 'Parus major']
['Tetrapoda', 'Animalia', 'Passeriformes', 'Aves', 'Pica', 'Chordata', 'Corvidae', 'Pica pica', 'Pica pica']
```

What I am looking to achieve is a single list with no duplicate entries. Also if you could show me how to have a string of the same, I'd really appreciate it.
An example of desired output:

```
['Tetrapoda', 'Animalia', 'Columbiformes', 'Aves', 'Columba', 'Chordata', 'Columbidae', 'Columba palumbus', 'Columba palumbus', 'Passeriformes', 'Corvidae', 'Pica pica' ...]
```

Comment: Store your contents in a `set` instead of a `list`, this will ensure there are no duplicates as that will be enforced by the container itself

Answer (score 2):

I would try out a `set` and then cast it to a `list`

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-set-into-a-list/